# Venn operation in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with list of employees who can be admin, dev, both or none

```
EMP_ID  IS_ADMIN    IS_DEV
    1       Y         Y
    2       Y         N
    3       N         Y
    4       N         N
```

I want to write a query so that when I request

1. IS_ADMIN=Y returns 1,2
2. IS_DEV=Y   returns 1,3
3. IS_DEV=Y, IS_ADMIN=Y returns 1,2,3
4. IS_DEV=N, IS_ADMIN=N or nothing returns 4

Is there anyway to incorporate this login in one query?

Comment: Not sure your logic makes sense here. If IS_DEV = Y or IS_ADMIN = Y should return 1,2,3 how can IS_DEV = N or IS_ADMIN = N return only 4? Shouldn't it return 2,3,4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify all the options as parameters, passing null to any parameter you don't care for and checking for null as a query condition. Your logic is a bit bent so it have to be programmed for exactly, every combination:

```
SELECT
  emp_id
FROM
  emps
WHERE
  (is_admin = 'Y' AND :isadmin = 'Y' AND :isdev is null)
  OR
  (is_dev = 'Y' AND :isdev = 'Y' AND :isadmin is null)
  OR
  (:isadmin = 'Y' AND :isdev = 'Y' AND (is_admin = 'Y' OR is_dev = 'Y'))
  OR
  (COALESCE(:isadmin, 'N') = 'N' AND COALESCE(:isdev, 'N') = 'N' AND is_admin = 'N' AND is_dev = 'N')
```

Your calling language of choice would set the parameters to 'Y', 'N' or null if it had no opinion, e.g. in c# for your case 1:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters["isadmin"].Value = "Y";
sqlCommand.Parameters["isdev"].Value = DBNull.Value;
using(var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()) ....
```